# iOS Draw Circle which is Clickable

Tags: iphone, geometry

I am drawing a circle using "CGContextAddEllipseInRect" method. After that I want to handle some events on click of the circle.

Not getting any methods for this.

Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is old but I wanted to throw my two cents out there anyway. I think what you're trying to accomplish is much easier using a button, as `Jennis` suggests. However, his button wasn't very round.

The property that needs to be changed to make a button round is `.cornerRadius`. Here's how this can be done using Jennis' code sample:

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2f alpha:.5f].CGColor;   
    button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 20; //key to rounded button
    [[self view] addSubview:button];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(yourEventTobeFired) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And the resulting output of this code:

[image]

This button is clickable, and upon clicking it will call the method `yourEventTobeFired`

If you refuse to use a button, then I'd suggest adding a `gesture recognizer` to your custom drawing, as I don't believe you can add an `action` like you can a button.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are drawing this circle in UIView, You can create Custom Button and add it to your view .

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 30);
[yourView addSubView:button];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(yourEventTobeFired) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Thats it.

Comment: I am drawing circle on a View only. But that circle is drawn based a radius in a rect Frame. How can I place a button on a circle?

Comment: Here is the code used to draw circle. Circle is drawn. But want that be clickable.

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0); if(needColor) CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor); else CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor); CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rect); CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor); CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect); 
CGContextStrokePath(context);

Comment: Any one faced this issue, please help me